# Deduction of Hölder Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, holder-inequality

If the Hölder inequality holds, we have
$$
|x\cdot y|\leq \| x\|_p\| y\|_q
$$
now if $y\neq 0$  this leads to
$$
\frac{|x\cdot y|}{\| y\|_q}\leq \| x\|_p
$$
Now my question.
Is this implication true:
$$
\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}}\frac{|x\cdot y|}{\| y\|_q}= \| x\|_p
$$
If this implication is not true, is the identity at least true? If so, can you give a hint for a proof?

And besides that, is there any literature about this identity? I have searched a lot but I have found nothing. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: What does the $\cdot$ mean?

Comment: @copper.hat scalar product

Comment: So you are working in $\mathbb{C}^n$, I presume.

Comment: @copper.hat In $\mathbb{R}^n$ yes

Answer (score 1):

Your question is basically about when the Holder inequality attains equality.
This is true if there exists a scalar $c$ such that $|y_i|^q = c|x_i|^p$ for all $i$.

So for example if $y_i = \text{sign}(x_i) \cdot x_i^{p/q}$ we have $|x \cdot y| = \sum_i |x_i|^{1+p/q} = \sum_i |x_i|^p$ and $\|y\|_q=\left(\sum_i |x_i|^p\right)^{1/q}$, whose ratio equals $\left(\sum_i |x_i|^p\right)^{1-1/q} = \left(\sum_i |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p} = \|x\|_p$.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Hölder inequality
$$
|x \cdot z| \leq\|x\|_{p}\|z\|_{q},
$$
from which follows
$$
\|x\|_{p} \geq \frac{|x \cdot z|}{\|z\|_{q}}
$$
and thus
\begin{equation}
    \|x\|_{p} \geq \sup _{z \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \backslash\{0\}} \frac{|x \cdot z|}{\|z\|_{q}} .
    \tag{1}
\end{equation}
To prove $(1)$, it suffices to find a $z=z(x)$ that yields equality in $(1)$. For this we consider the following cases.

Case $p=1$. Let us set
$$
z_{k}=\operatorname{sgn} x_{k}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
1, x_{k} \geq 0 \\
-1, x_{k}<0
\end{array}\right. .
$$
Then $\|z\|_{\infty}=1$ and.
$$
x \cdot z=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} \operatorname{sgn} x_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|=\|x\|_{1}=\|z\|_{\infty}\|x\|_{1} .
$$
Case $p=\infty$. There is an $i$ with
$$
\left|x_{i}\right|=\operatorname{max}_{k}\left|x_{k}\right|=\|x\|_{\infty}
$$
so we set
$$
z_{i}=\operatorname{sgn} x_{i} \text { and } z_{k}=0 \text { for all } k \neq i .
$$
Then $\|z\|_{1}=1$ and
$$
x \cdot z=x_{i} \operatorname{sgn} x_{i}=\left|x_{i}\right|=\|x\|_{\infty}=\|z\|_{1}\|x\|_{\infty} \cdot
$$
Case $p \in(1, \infty)$. Let's set
$$
z_{k}=\left(\operatorname{sgn} x_{k}\right)\left|x_{k}\right|^{p-1}.
$$
Then we have
$$
x \cdot z=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{k} z_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\operatorname{sgn} x_{k})\left|x_{k}\right|^{p-1} x_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|^{p}=\|x\|_{p}^{p}
$$
and
$$
\|z\|_{q}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|z_{k}\right|^{q}\right)^{1 / q}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|^{(p- 1) q}\right)^{1 / q}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|x_{k}\right|^{p}\right)^{1 / q}=\|x\|_{p}^{p / q}.
$$
Thus
$$
\|x\|_{p}\|z\|_{q}=\|x\|_{p}^{1+p / q}=\|x\|_{p}^{1+(p-1)}=\|x\|_{p}^{p}=|x \cdot z|,
$$
which is what we wanted to show. $\quad \blacksquare$